# Asp.Net MVC 3 validate 2 dependent fields

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, validation

Say I have a form that has fields to gather data about future conferences (not the real domain but will suffice for the purposes of this question). Part of the validation is that a new event can only happen once in that year so for instance if you have a "stackoverflow getmessyandrunk conference" that happens in 2012 - the user shouldn't be allowed to enter a new event with the same name and year...

Now - what I have tried so far is to add a remote validator to each of the fields:

one for the event name field that uses the AdditionalFields property to include the year field and one for the year field which uses the AdditionalFields to include the event name field.

it doesn't work - if I try to add an event with the same name and year it adds an error to just the year field, correcting it fixes it, then trying again it adds an error to the name field and year field, correcting the name field to make the combination unique only removes the error from the name field - it goes on like this...

How are others doing this?

Comment: Do you need to support client side validation as well? Can't you do the validation on the server? Also this seems to be a domain logic validation error. Why not simply adding it to the ModelState and then using the `Html.ValidationSummary` helper? Why do you need to associate this error to a particular field when in fact there could be multiple dependent fields?

Comment: That makes sense.. I'll mull this over for a bit... would be good to get contextual feedback on the fields that are causing the error... also, I'm not a big fan of adding having valdiation in the action and adding errors to the modelstate manually...

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer using data annotations for validation, I would recommend that you just use the Foolproof validation library that is available on Codeplex: https://foolproof.codeplex.com/

It supports, amongst others, the following "requiredif" validation attributes / decorations:

```
[RequiredIf]
[RequiredIfNot]
[RequiredIfTrue]
[RequiredIfFalse]
[RequiredIfEmpty]
[RequiredIfNotEmpty]
[RequiredIfRegExMatch]
[RequiredIfNotRegExMatch]
```

To get started is easy:

- Download the package from the provided link
- Add a reference to the included .dll file
- Import the included javascript files
- Ensure that your views references the included javascript files from within its HTML for unobtrusive javascript and jquery validation.

If you don't like mixing your domain and and validation logic by decorating your domain classes with validation attributes, you can always opt for the powerful fluent validation.  You can find the library for it here:
https://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/
It is unfortunately server-side only, but a suitable option if seperation of concerns is of importance to you... and context is not lost due to the validation being tied to a specific field. (See here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/326647/FluentValidation-and-Unity)